# passing function template prototype as argument

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, compiler-errors, clang

I am trying to pass a templated function to another, like this:

```cpp
template<typename T = bool>
void fun() {}

template<typename F>
void higher_order_fun( const F & f) {
    f();
}

int main () {
    //higher_order_fun(fun<>); //works
    higher_order_fun(fun);
}
```

In `gcc10.2` I am able to pass `fun` (a template prototype) in the same way
as the specified type `fun<>`.
Note that this does not work if I don't have the default template parameter T=bool.

In `Clang11` this doesn't work.
See https://godbolt.org/z/9WfMdc.

What is going on here?

Comment: I would say gcc bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>*All standard references below refer to [N4659: March 2017 post-Kona working draft/C++17 DIS](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/).*</sub>

---

This is arguably a GCC bug (/extension feature), although I have not been able to find a ticket for it.

As per [[temp.names]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.names#1), you may refer to a *template specialization* by means of a *template-id*. The grammar for the latter does not allow omission of the the angle brackets `<>`, even if the *template-argument-list* within it may be empty (*opt*):

> A template specialization can be referred to by a *template-id*:
>
> ```
> simple-template-id:
>   template-name < template-argument-list_opt >
>
> template-id:
>   simple-template-id
>   operator-function-id < template-argument-list_opt >
>   literal-operator-id < template-argument-list_opt >
> ```

In your case, you want to *refer* to the specialization `fun<bool>` of the function template `fun`, which is the same specialization you can refer to by making use of the default template argument for the single type template argument of `fun`, namely as `fun<>`. You cannot, however, refer to the `fun<bool>` specialization only by specifying `fun`; the latter does not refer to a *specialization*, and thus, your program is ill-formed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify what is `T` when you pass `fun` because you need an instantiation of that parameter to build that function. Compiler needs to infer `T` somehow.

Compiler assumes that `T` is of class `bool` with `fun` or `fun<>`, but you cannot get rid of the default template parameter or it will not be able to deduce it.

Comment: yeah its clear why it doesn't work without the default. my question rather aims at whether i can use `fun` and `fun<>` interchangably in this case, because they are definitly different things.

Comment: Exactly, they are different, that is why not compiling makes sense :) It should not be allowed to overlook the template definition of a function and use it as a non-templated function.